# one way anova and MSA

Tags: anova, expected-value

Im  new here
I wonder if anyone has the proof of the expectation of the MSA in the one way anova, I know what it is equal to but I need the proof

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean MSE (mean squared error)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.